# jquery.ui.resizeable.js doesn't contain text if too much to fit in container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the ui.resizeable.js plugin and I'm dynamically loading a txt or html file into the div (in the example below it already in the `div`) but when the text more than the container can handle the text appears outside the container. I've looked at the options and there doesn't seem to be a solution except to determine the size of the file when loaded and set the minimum height and width.

http://jsfiddle.net/sunbelt57/jC6f3/7/

Comment: I am having trouble undertstanding your jsfiddle, do you need to include the jquery-ui plugin to see the issue?

Comment: I didn't have the proper settings in the frameworks & extensions at the upper left set. YOu should be able to see it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must add overflow:hidden

```
#resizable1 { width: 200px; height: 150px; padding: 5px; overflow:hidden;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jC6f3/9/